# How to extend xUnit to run each test case as a separate executable

Tags: junit, fortran, mpi, xunit

I have created a unit testing framework, pFUnit, that largely follows the current design of JUnit, and am looking for suggestions on how to extend this framework to handle a certain situation.  For the curious, this framework pFUnit is written in OO Fortran (yes -- Fortran now has OO capabilities!) and supports distributed programing using MPI.   But I think the only pertinent aspect about language choice is that if the SUT actually crashes, the testing framework does as well.   Fortunately, that is a relatively rare situation, but it still happens often enough to scream for a solution.

My intent had been to provide an alternate TestRunner that will run each test as a separate executable as an RPC or something similar.   The run-time overhead for this can be large, especially when launching MPI repeatedly, so I do not want to make this the default behavior.   Unfortunately, when I looked into how to code this approach, I found that TestRunner does not appear to be ideally suited for such an extension as it only manages the run of the top of a nested seriest of TestSuite's.

I can see a klunky way of making it work by having the TestRunner navigate the nested structure, but it would undermine the role of TestSuite in a major way.

Actually, the easiest approach I've come up with is to subclass TestResult.   TestResult invokes runBare() on each TestCase,  so an extension could simply be to launch a separate executable that just invokes that runBare() method and returns any exceptions.     This solution bothers my sense of aesthetics, as it is not the sort of thing for which TestResult ought to be responsible.

I could also add a launch() method to TestCase that checks some global parameter to determine whether to run as a procedure or to launch as a separate executable.  This seems inelegant, but is probably not much more difficult than the TestResult extension I mentioned before.

Hopefully this is enough background that a person with deeper understanding of JUnit's design can suggest a better/cleaner approach than the alternatives I've proposed.  Or failing that offer me absolution for the design sins I have proposed.

Comment: Are you open sourcing this so other devs could see the code? This appears to be such a specific topic that you might not get the help you're looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit doesn't do forking as such, it leaves that to the things that invoke JUnit, such as Eclipse or Maven surefire.

Eclipse forks the jvm and then executes in the separate JVM, and communicates the result through a connection to the forked JVM.

Maven surefire has options where the user can control how and when to fork - it has different options for forking, see [Maven Surefire - Fork Options and Parallel Test Execution](http://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/fork-options-and-parallel-execution.html).

One option would be to have a ForkingTestRunner, a TestRunner which forks. Then you could do the equivalent of `@RunWith(ForkingTestRunner.class)`, which forks once per test method.

If this is still too slow, you could fork a runner, and communicate the results back through a socket or something to the monitor process. If the SUT crashes, then the monitor process detects this and fails the test and restarts the runner (but with a cut down list).

This way you'd only have one fork per set of tests, unless the SUT crashes a lot.

Comment: (Sorry for the early <return>).  My understanding of Java annotations is limited.  Wouldn't users of my framework need to put the `@RunWith` in each TestCase to get the functionality I want.  Except that I don't want them to modify their test code at all.  Rather I want them to simply use an alternative runner that has the fork behavior.  If `@RunWith` can "propagate down" from the top of a tree of suites, that is great, but I don't see how that works, and thus cannot see how to implement it on my end.

Comment: The @RunWith was just an example, in case you wanted to leave the choice of users to fork or not. If not, you can implement the TestRunner that forks, runs the tests and re-forks in the case where the process exits.

Comment: It appears to me that it would be very complex for the parent process to re-fork, as the child process would have been at an arbitrary location in the test tree.  Yes - there it will have all the information about what successfully ran, but that's not the same as re-establishing various test-iterators at intermediate states.   I'm probably just missing something simple here about how the parent process manages this recover.

Comment: Maybe I'm not being clear enough. When the runner forks, it passes a list of tests to execute to the new process. In the case where there was a crash, you'd pass a cut down version of the list, without the already executed tests.

Comment: Matthew - thanks again.   I think you were plenty clear, but "the student was not ready to learn ...".   I had previously eliminated this approach in my mind because it seems to usurp the role of TestSuite.  But I should have realized that is why JUnit has TestSuite::tests().  My framework does not have that (yet), as it had no need.  Just FYI, I now need to implement a client-server, as fork() does not play well with MPI.   But I've done that bit before in the previous procedural implementation of my framework.  Cheers.